# How to write exactly LaTeX commands in a PDF stream?

Tags: luatex

I try to write LaTeX formula in PDF stream and it almost works for me, but after `\begin` and `\end` I have a space, so for example instead of `\begin{multline}` I have `\begin {multline}`. The same situation I have for `\end`. How can I fix it using LaTeX commands and `expl3` syntactics (I ask two ways because I want to understand how to fix it not only using LaTeX style but also with `expl3`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3pdf,}

    \begin{document}
    test
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \pdf_uncompress: %why not works,or it issue of l3pdf?
    \directlua{pdf.setcompresslevel(0)}
    \pdf_object_new:nn{obj}{stream}
    \pdf_object_write:nx{obj}{{/Type\c_space_tl some_type}{\detokenize{\begin{multline}a/x=1\\a^2+x^2=0\end{multline}}}}
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Not possible. `\detokenize` basically performs `\string` on every token and that means that a space is inserted after every control sequence.  That is hardcoded in the TeX engine core.

Comment: Here is the source code for the `print_cs` function, for reference: https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/70748eb187ba1f0b58ec5261f557d514cd8f18bf/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/printing.c#L779-L819  The `print_char(' ');` statements are the ones that result in the space after control sequence names.

Comment: @Henri Menke Ok,and how avoid printing of space after \begin or \end?

Comment: Read my first comment again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3pdf,}
\ExplSyntaxOn
 \pdf_uncompress: %should be in the preamble ...
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
test
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdf_object_new:nn{obj}{stream}
\tl_set_rescan:Nnn\l_tmpa_tl 
 {
  \char_set_catcode_other:n {92}
  \char_set_catcode_other:n {94}
  \char_set_catcode_other:n {95}
 }
 {\begin{multline}a/x=1\\a^2+x^2=0\end{multline}}

\pdf_object_write:nx{obj}{{/Type\c_space_tl some_type}{\l_tmpa_tl}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

seems to work, but it is probably rather slow.

Comment: Maybe you want to mention what this actually does.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you very much for your help,I will test it. And now it interesting for me,how to do this using standard latex2 commands,or this possible to do this only with expl3? Also it very interesting for me,catcodes of chars,which we change,restore after applying of this function. Thank you very much again for your answer.

Comment: expl3 is build on tex, so yes you could do it without- but I don't see a point to spent time to write my own version if expl3 provides something working

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer But using expl3 sometimes require more code,when latex 2 and not all,who knows usual latex,knows expl3. Also I want to compare solution for usual latex and for expl3.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer In some situations i need in expanding of commands,for example i have: \newcommand{\test}[2]{#1+#2=#1-#2}. I want to write \tl_set_rescan:Nnn\l_tmpb_tl 
 {
  \char_set_catcode_other:n {92}
  \char_set_catcode_other:n {94}
  \char_set_catcode_other:n {95}
 }
 {
\begin{equation}\test{1}{0}\end{equation}},but in this case i will not get expanded command in pdf stream,even if i will use \expandafter before \test command. How to fix it?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy The thing is, the team have spent _years_ writing a set of libraries that _work well_: there is a reason we are not that keen on 'just pulling out the ideas' into classical constructs. There are loads of data structures, accessors, utilities, etc. one ends up re-coding. `expl3` loads on plain and ConTeXt as well as LaTeX.

Comment: As Joseph wrote: expl3 is a very well working powerful tool and I won't spent any time on tries to avoid it. Regarding the expansion: If your content can contain arbitrary macros which need different expansions, your system is not practical. How should latex know that \int should not be expanded, but \testA once, and \testB twice?